# VHDL-“Signal cannot be synthesized, bad synchronous description”

Tags: vhdl, active-hdl

I have a error while Synthesize this code in Xillinx. This error is:
"Signal Z_1 cannot be synthesized, bad synchronous description"

```
entity uk3 is
     port(
         rst : in BIT;
         C : in INTEGER;
         clk : in BIT;
         S : out INTEGER
         );
end uk3;

--}} End of automatically maintained section

architecture uk3 of uk3 is
begin
    process (C,clk,rst)
    variable Z_1 : integer:=0;
    begin
        if rst='1' then Z_1:=0;
        elsif rst='0'and clk'event and clk='1'and C=1
            then 
            Z_1:=Z_1 + 1;
        elsif rst='0'and clk'event and clk='1'and C=2
            then
            Z_1:=Z_1 + 2;   
        else
            Z_1:=Z_1;
        end if;
        S<=Z_1;
        end process;

     -- enter your statements here --

end uk3;
```

why? Pls

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should properly describe your synchronous process. This is not c/c++, you should use proper template for that, or it will not synthesize. I particular, you should only have one statement sensitive for edge of the clock.

For example:

```
process (clk,rst)
variable Z_1 : integer:=0;
begin
    if rst='1' then 
        Z_1:=0;
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        case C is
            when 1 =>
                Z_1:=Z_1 + 1;
            when 2 => 
                Z_1:=Z_1 + 2;
            when others =>
                null;
        end case;
        S<=Z_1;
    end if;

end process;
```

Note, that there is no C in sensitivity list, as it is not needed. If there is no rising edge, it will not fire anyway (it is synchronous to rising edge of the clock)

I havn't tested this code, but it should work.

And actually, why don't you make Z_1 signal, instead of variable?

Comment: Teraz nie da się wykompliować: architecture uk3 of uk3 is
begin
 process (clk,rst)
 variable Z_1 : INTEGER:=0; 
 begin
  if rst='1' then Z_1:=0;
  elsif rising_edge(clk) then
   case C is
    when 1=>
    Z_1:=Z_1 +1;
    when 2=>
    Z_1:=Z_1 + 2;
   end case;
   D<=Z_1;
  end if; 
  end process;
     
  -- enter your statements here --

end uk3;   wyskakują errory  Podczas kompilowania:
.

Comment: # Error: COMP96_0093: uk3.vhd : (47, 21): Actual parameter types in subprogram call do not match subprogram formal parameter types.
# Error: COMP96_0301: uk3.vhd : (48, 4): The choice OTHERS must be present when all alternatives are not covered

Comment: @Pietryno See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539962/errorxst827-signal-count-cannot-be-synthesized-bad-synchronous-description/36543625#36543625).

Comment: @Pietryno Your comments seem to be another question. If so, please ask another question.

Comment: i would suggest using synchronous reset. And to make `Z_1` a signal instead of a variable.

Comment: I agree with JHBonarius. And you actually get your answer in compiler message:) You need to comver all cases in case statement. Edited. Also don't use polish language here, this way only me and few other people will be able to understand you.